# How to save country code with phone number?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

How do I initialize `utilsScript`?

In the **[intl-tel-input gem documentation](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input#utilities-script)** it says...

> **Recommended**: initialize the plugin with the utilsScript option to
>   enable formatting/validation, and to allow you to extract full
>   international numbers using getNumber.

I want to initialize the plugin because I want to use `getNumber`.

```
<%= telephone_field_tag :number,  nil, placeholder: 'Enter Phone Number', class: 'form-control', id: "country" %>

<script>
  $("#country").intlTelInput({
    separateDialCode: true
  });

  $("form").submit(function() {
    myInput.val(myInput.intlTelInput("getNumber")); // Without getNumber the international code doesn't save in the parameters
  });
</script>
```

I'm also using **[intl-tel-input-rails gem](https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/intl-tel-input-rails)** to package the **intl-tel-input** assets (JavaScripts, stylesheets, and images) for the Rails asset pipeline.

My current script triggers this error...

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myInput is not defined
```

Comment: can you `console.log(myInput.intlTelInput("getNumber"))` in your second JS example (using submit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched gems...

https://github.com/ispyropoulos/intl-tel-input-rails

because this I can include the line `//= require libphonenumber/utils`.

And in the script I adjusted to...

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  $('#country').val($('#country').intlTelInput("getNumber"));
});
```

And I also needed to use `text_field`

Answer (score 0):

include

```
 <script src="assets/plugins/build/js/utils.js"></script>
```

then call 
         `var number = $("#phone").intlTelInput("getNumber");`